Matching antenna at 4.2 GHz using an LC network
I want to match an antenna using an LC matching network:
Operation frequency: 4.2 GHz
Vacuum wavelength: 7.2 cm
Cable:
Source Impedance: 50 Ω\
The antenna impedance is unknown, but it is approximately a full wavelength and I think it should be around 100 Ω at 4.2 GHz.
My mathematica code (below) tells me I would need a variable capacitor and a variable inductor that i can tune around 80pF and 3 nH. This is very low and I am having trouble finding parts that can be tuned around these values.
What is the best way to do this? Is the LC network a good idea? 
Can I just put enough capacitors in series and enough inductors in parallel to lower the effective capacitances and inductions? Does that work, or will I run into some unforeseen issue? In the end the signal going to the antenna should be on the order of a Watt.\
Do you know of a vendor where I can find the right parts?
freq=4200*10^6;
\[Omega]=2\[Pi]*freq;
sourceImpedance=50;
antennaImpedance=75-I*100;
LImpedance[\[Omega]_,L_]:=I*L*\[Omega];
CImpedance[\[Omega]_,C_]:=1/(I*C*\[Omega])

LParallelCSeriesImpedance[\[Omega]_,antennaImpedance_,L_,C_]:=(1/(antennaImpedance+CImpedance[\[Omega],C])+1/LImpedance[\[Omega],L])^-1;
LSeriesCParallelImpedance[\[Omega]_,antennaImpedance_,L_,C_]:=(1/(antennaImpedance+LImpedance[\[Omega],L])+1/CImpedance[\[Omega],C])^-1;
LParallelCSeriesImpedanceAlt[\[Omega]_,antennaImpedance_,L_,C_]:=(1/antennaImpedance+1/LImpedance[\[Omega],L])^-1+CImpedance[\[Omega],C];
LSeriesCParallelImpedanceAlt[\[Omega]_,antennaImpedance_,L_,C_]:=(1/antennaImpedance+1/CImpedance[\[Omega],C])^-1+LImpedance[\[Omega],L];
ReflectionRatio[sourceImpedance_,finalImpedance_]:=(finalImpedance-sourceImpedance)/(finalImpedance+sourceImpedance);


solutions=NMinimize[{Norm[ReflectionRatio[sourceImpedance,LParallelCSeriesImpedance[\[Omega],antennaImpedance,L,C]]],L>0,C>0,L<10^-7,C<10^-8},{L\[Element]Reals,C\[Element]Reals}];
Plot[Norm[ReflectionRatio[sourceImpedance,LParallelCSeriesImpedance[omega*(2\[Pi])*10^9,antennaImpedance,L/. solutions[[2]],C/. solutions[[2]]]]],{omega,4,4.4},AxesLabel->{"\[Omega] (GHz)","|\[CapitalGamma](\[Omega])|"},PlotRange->All,PlotLabel->StringForm["Subscript[C, opt]=``pF \n Subscript[L, opt] =`` nH",(C/. solutions[[2]])/10^-12,(L/. solutions[[2]])/10^-9],ImageSize->Large]
solutions=NMinimize[{Norm[ReflectionRatio[sourceImpedance,LSeriesCParallelImpedance[\[Omega],antennaImpedance,L,C]]],L>0,C>0,L<10^-7,C<10^-8},{L\[Element]Reals,C\[Element]Reals}];
Plot[Norm[ReflectionRatio[sourceImpedance,LSeriesCParallelImpedance[omega*(2\[Pi])*10^9,antennaImpedance,L/. solutions[[2]],C/. solutions[[2]]]]],{omega,4,4.4},AxesLabel->{"\[Omega] (GHz)","|\[CapitalGamma](\[Omega])|"},PlotRange->All,PlotLabel->StringForm["Subscript[C, opt]=``pF \n Subscript[L, opt] =`` nH",(C/. solutions[[2]])/10^-12,(L/. solutions[[2]])/10^-9],ImageSize->Large]
solutions=NMinimize[{Norm[ReflectionRatio[sourceImpedance,LSeriesCParallelImpedanceAlt[\[Omega],antennaImpedance,L,C]]],L>0,C>0,L<10^-7,C<10^-8},{L\[Element]Reals,C\[Element]Reals}];
Plot[Norm[ReflectionRatio[sourceImpedance,LSeriesCParallelImpedanceAlt[omega*(2\[Pi])*10^9,antennaImpedance,L/. solutions[[2]],C/. solutions[[2]]]]],{omega,4,4.4},AxesLabel->{"\[Omega] (GHz)","|\[CapitalGamma](\[Omega])|"},PlotRange->All,PlotLabel->StringForm["Subscript[C, opt]=``pF \n Subscript[L, opt] =`` nH",(C/. solutions[[2]])/10^-12,(L/. solutions[[2]])/10^-9],ImageSize->Large]
solutions=NMinimize[{Norm[ReflectionRatio[sourceImpedance,LParallelCSeriesImpedanceAlt[\[Omega],antennaImpedance,L,C]]],L>0,C>0,L<10^-7,C<10^-8},{L\[Element]Reals,C\[Element]Reals}];
Plot[Norm[ReflectionRatio[sourceImpedance,LParallelCSeriesImpedanceAlt[omega*(2\[Pi])*10^9,antennaImpedance,L/. solutions[[2]],C/. solutions[[2]]]]],{omega,4,4.4},AxesLabel->{"\[Omega] (GHz)","|\[CapitalGamma](\[Omega])|"},PlotRange->All,PlotLabel->StringForm["Subscript[C, opt]=``pF \n Subscript[L, opt] =`` nH",(C/. solutions[[2]])/10^-12,(L/. solutions[[2]])/10^-9],ImageSize->Large]


You don't find 3nH inductors because a few mm of wire in a straight line has more than 3nH of inductance.

The way everybody else does this is to use tuned stubs of transmission line to match impedances. every inch of transmission line possesses a well-known quantity of inductance and capacitance and the ARRL Antenna Book shows you how to use pieces of transmission line to do the trick.

For instance: a 38.5° long segment of 150-ohm TL in series brings 75-100j down to 49-0.1j. In this context I guess you'd probably realize it using a PCB transmission line, having a short segment at the end with a different geometry.
